# XmlReader thinks all elements are EndElements

Tags: c#, xml, stream

```
        StringBuilder returnXml = new StringBuilder();
        returnXml.Append("DATE TIME,FUNCTION,TOTAL\n");
        String Date = "", Function = "", Total = "";
        StreamReader xmlStream = getBlobData(logType, serial, blobStorageCredentials);

        //string adf = xmlStream.ReadToEnd();

        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream);
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {

                switch (xmlReader.Name)
                {
                    case "OperationType":
                        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                        Function = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        break;

                    case "TotalCounter":
                        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                        Total = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        break;

                    case "LogDateTime":
                        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                        Date = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        break;

                    case "Entries":
                        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                        {
                            returnXml.Append(Date);
                            returnXml.Append(",");
                            returnXml.Append(Function);
                            returnXml.Append(",");
                            returnXml.Append(Total);
                            returnXml.Append("\n");
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

        }
        return returnXml.ToString();
```

So all of those cases aren't being entered ever. If I comment in:

```
   //string xmlString = xmlStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Then xmlString is this in the debugger (it looks correct):

http://pastebin.com/8Uj2GwSB

Why does XmlReader think all of the Nodes are EndElements? I'm struggling because It's not my code. Got handed off to me...

Comment: Can't see your xml. Link is timing out. Can you post your xml on SO.

Answer (score 0):

When you uncomment this your StreamReader moves the file pointer to the end of the xml file.

```
//string xmlString = xmlStream.ReadToEnd();
```

So even if you create XmlReader from the xmlStream you don't have any bytes left to read.
If you would like to read the stream into the string as above and re-use it for the XmlReader, you need to "rewind" the stream.
This can be achieved by setting the Position property and clearing the buffer like:

```
xmlStream.Position = 0;
xmlStream.DiscardBufferedData();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this and it was my first attempt at fixing. I've checked the position with a debugger and it appears correct. Were you able to see the XML? I think it may be part of the issue.